# Add ListViews to LinearLayout but only first added is shown

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

i'm trying to add two listviews to linearlayout but only first Listview is shown, anyone does know why?

```
private void populateListView(ConstraintLayout root, List<Product> products){
    ....

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    ...
    ListView listView = (ListView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view_product, null);
    listView.setId(View.generateViewId());
    listView.setLayoutParams(newParams);
    ...

   
    ListView listView2 = (ListView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_view_product, null);
    listView2.setId(View.generateViewId());
    listView2.setLayoutParams(newParams);
    ...

    LinearLayout linearLayoutView = (LinearLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.fragment_ll_home);

    linearLayoutView.addView(listView2,0);
    linearLayoutView.addView(listView,1);

}
```

Comment: ListViews should not share LayoutParams. Make a new LayoutParams for each ListView.

Comment: Thanks very much @cheticamp